# Thevenin Equivalent Voltage and Resistance with Multiple Parallel Sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I am looking for help with finding the Thevenin equivalent voltage in the circuit pictured, basically 2c on the list of problems.

I have so far done the loop equations and have come out with the following:

Loop 1 (left hand side) 
E1-R1I1-R2(I1-I2)-E2 = 0

Loop 2 (right hand side)
E2-R2(I2-I1)-R3I2+E3 = 0

I am pretty sure the next step I have to do is combine these equations to solve for either I1 or I2.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to convert E1 and R1 into a current source in parallel with R1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework without an attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Many methods to solve. One simple method for this particular type of circuit is using Millman's theorem.

$$V_{th} = V_{AB} = \frac {\frac{E_1}{R_1}+\frac{E_2}{R_2}+\frac{-E_3}{R_3}}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}}$$

[Millman's theorem](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/millmans-theorem/)

Or

Convert all *voltage sources + series resistances* To *current sources with parallel resistances*. And multiply the net current by net resistance across AB.

Or

Use superposition theorem to find \$V_{AB}\$, considering one source at a time. Finally add the \$V_{ABs}\$ you got for individual sources.

Or

Apply nodal analysis at node A and find the voltage at node A. That would be \$V_{AB}\$

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I'm assuming if I were to use the method of converting all the voltage and series resistances to current sources, I would use mesh analysis and end up with the two loop equations: Loop 1 (left hand side) E1-R1I1-R2(I1-I2)-E2 = 0

Loop 2 (right hand side) E2-R2(I2-I1)-R3I2+E3 = 0

Comment: If you converted all sources then no need of mesh analysis. Parallel current sources is equivalent to one current source with summation of all sources. Resistors are parallel too. They will become one single equivalent resistance. In the end only one current source and one resistance remains.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is three Thevenin voltage sources meeting at a common node. There is a general solution worth being familiar with (since the situation is common enough.)

For \$N\$ Thevenin voltage sources (with their series resistances) tied to the same node, the resulting single Thevenin voltage source is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X&=\frac{\sum^N_{i=1}\left[V_i\cdot\prod^N_{j\ne i} R_j\right]}{\sum^N_{i=1}\left[ \prod^N_{j\ne i} R_j\right]}\\\\R_{X}&=\frac{\prod^N_{i=1} R_i}{\sum^N_{i=1}\left[ \prod^N_{j\ne i} R_j\right]}
\end{align*}$$

Where \$V_X\$ is the resulting Thevenin voltage and \$R_X\$ is the resulting Thevenin resistance.

For your case of \$N=3\$, this results in:

$$\begin{align*}
V_X&=\frac{V_1\: R_2\: R_3 + V_2\: R_1\: R_3 + V_3\: R_1\: R_2}{R_2\: R_3 + R_1\: R_3 + R_1\: R_2}\\\\R_{X}&=\frac{R_1\: R_2\: R_3}{R_2\: R_3 + R_1\: R_3 + R_1\: R_2}
\end{align*}$$

Nodal analysis is more general and can be applied in your situation to get the same result:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_X}{R_1}+\frac{V_X}{R_2}+\frac{V_X}{R_3}&=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}\\\\
V_X\cdot\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}\right)&=\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}\\\\
V_X\cdot\left(\frac{R_2\:R_3}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}+\frac{R_1\:R_3}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}+\frac{R_1\:R_2}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}\right)&=\frac{V_1\:R_2\:R_3}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}+\frac{V_2\:R_1\:R_3}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}+\frac{V_3\:R_1\:R_2}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}\\\\
V_X\cdot\frac{R_2: R_3 + R_1\: R_3 + R_1\: R_2}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}&=\frac{V_1\:R_2\:R_3+V_2\:R_1\:R_3+V_3\:R_1\:R_2}{R_1\:R_2\:R_3}\\\\
V_X&=\frac{V_1\: R_2\: R_3 + V_2\: R_1\: R_3 + V_3\: R_1\: R_2}{R_2\: R_3 + R_1\: R_3 + R_1\: R_2}\end{align*}$$